# How to change programmatically the text of a Word Bookmark

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to process a Word document and change (the text of) a bookmark.

I exported my Word document to flat xml format to help establish the structure of the document - here is a fragment

```
<w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="CustomerName"/>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="001E4487">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="MyTypeRegular" 
              w:hAnsi="MyTypeRegular" 
              w:cs="MyType V2 Regular"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>[CustomerName]</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
```

The bit I need to change is `<w:t>[CustomerName]</w:t>` which should then become, for example `<w:t>Some Punter</w:t>`

so in my VBA i am hoping to be able to do something like this ...

```
  Dim bkm As Bookmark
  For Each bkm In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
    bkm.Text = "Some Punter"
  Next bkm
```

only `BookMark` does not have a `Text` property

How do Access that little data item in the square Brackets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A word bookmark doesn't have a text property, but its range property does.

Use bkm.Range.Text = "Some Punter"

Note that once you change the text, the bookmark will be removed from the Word Document.  In order to keep the bookmark you need to do:

```
    Dim bkm As Bookmark
    Dim bkmName As String
    Dim bkmRng As Range
    Dim NewText As String

    NewText = "Some Punter"

    For Each bkm In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        Set bkmRng = bkm.Range
        bkmName = bkm.Name
        bkm.Range.Text = NewText
        bkmRng.End = bkmRng.Start + Len(NewText)
        Bookmarks.Add(Name:=bkmName, Range:=bkmRng)
    Next bkm
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for this that is not perfect but is less complicated:  In place of the bookmark, use ActiveX text box and in place of cross-reference use ActiveX label.  Then make change event (or LostFocus Event) for the text box:  LabelName.Caption = TextboxName.Text.  Formatting can be as desired.  Alignment of text outside controls may be needed using Font> Advanced > Position > Raised.  This may not be acceptable in all instances, but it often can be.  Requires no update of field.