# VBA optimization robust code

Tags: vba, ms-word, robustness

So I'm completely new to VBA. I have a java-fetish so I'm not new to programming, however manipulating office documents just seemed easier with VBA. 
Anyway, on topic:

I'm currently automating things in the company (This example is creating a contract). However, using Java, I always learned to make robust code and although the VBA code now works, I'm not happy with it because it requires a lot of 'friendliness' of the user. So my question is (I hope you don't mind), could you give me a nudge in the right direction to make my code way more robust?

Here's the code:

```
Function spaties(Name As String) As String
' Function used to ensure the length of a String (Working with Range)
Dim index As Integer

While (Len(Name) < 30)
Name = Name + " "
Wend

spaties = Name

End Function
```

---

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
'
'ActiveDocument.Range(26101, 26102).Text = "d"
    StartUndoSaver
    Dim firma As String
    firma = InputBox("Voor welke onderaannemer? (Zonder hoofdletters)" + Chr(10) + "(nicu, sorin of marius)")
    Dim werf As String
    werf = InputBox("Over welke Werf gaat het?")
    Dim datum As String
    datum = InputBox("Op welke datum spreekt het contract? (dd/mm/yyyy)")
    With ActiveDocument
        .Range(25882, 25899).Text = datum
        ActiveDocument.Range(575, 605).Text = spaties(werf)
        ActiveDocument.Range(1279, 1309).Text = spaties(werf)
  End With

  Select Case Len(firma)
  Case 4
    With ActiveDocument
        .Range(26168, 26181).Text = "Nicu Dinita"
        .Range(26062, 26088).Text = "Badi Woodconstruct SRL"
        .Range(11359, 11371).Text = "Nicu Dinita"

  End With
  Case 5
    With ActiveDocument
        .Range(26168, 26181).Text = "Asavei Sorin"
        .Range(26062, 26088).Text = "BELRO  INTERIOR DESIGN SRL"
        .Range(11359, 11371).Text = "Asavei Sorin"

  End With
  Case 6
    With ActiveDocument
        .Range(26168, 26181).Text = "Ivan Maricel"
        .Range(26062, 26088).Text = "Solomon & Aaron Construct"
        .Range(11359, 11371).Text = "Ivan Maricel"

  End With

  End Select
    Dim prijs As String
    Dim besch As String
    Dim eenh As String

     Dim hoev As Integer
     hoev = InputBox("Hoeveel artikels zijn er?")
    Dim index As Integer
    index = 1
    While (index <= hoev)
    besch = InputBox("Beschrijving van het artikel (engels)")
    prijs = InputBox("prijs van het artikel")
    eenh = InputBox("Eenheid van het artikel")

    With ActiveDocument
        .Range(5701, 5702).Text = "" + vbTab + spaties2(besch, prijs, eenh) + Chr(10) + vbTab
    End With
    index = index + 1
    Wend
        With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
    .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Raes G. Schrijnwerken BVBA" + vbTab + vbTab + datum + Chr(10) + "Robert Klingstraat 5" + Chr(10) + "8940 Wervik"
    .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Overeenkomst tot onderaanneming" + Chr(10) + "met betrekking tot:" + werf
    .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).PageNumbers.Add PageNumberAlignment:=wdAlignPageNumberRight
End With
    If firma = "sorin" Then
        ActiveDocument.Range(254, 255).ImportFragment "Z:\Raes Netwerk DATA\professioneel\004 Sjablonen\belro.docx", False


    Else
        If firma = "nicu" Then
        With ActiveDocument
            .Range(254, 255).ImportFragment "Z:\Raes Netwerk DATA\professioneel\004 Sjablonen\Nicu.docx", False
            End With
        Else
            If firma = "marius" Then
                ActiveDocument.Range(254, 255).ImportFragment "Z:\Raes Netwerk DATA\professioneel\004 Sjablonen\Marius.docx", False
            End If
        End If
    End If

    ActiveDocument.PrintOut
    ActiveDocument.PrintOut



End Sub
```

---

```
Function spaties2(artikel As String, prijs As String, eenh As String) As String
'Another function to ensure length of String
Dim index As Integer
Dim eind As String
eind = "" + artikel + vbTab + vbTab + prijs + "€/" + eenh
While (Len(eind) < 100)
eind = eind + " "
Wend

spaties2 = eind

End Function
```

As you can see, the code is very basic. And although it works, it's no good to deliver.

The two defined `Functions` are simply formatting the String of the user because obviously the name of something is not always the same length.

I'd like to cut out the `Range` properties, because in my opinion, that's what makes the program so sensitive to changes.

Any and all suggestions are welcome.

*note: For the moment, the contract can have three different 'target parties' so that's why the `Select Case` statement is there. It's going to be completely useless if it should grow but for now it works.*

Comment: If the code is working and only needs improvements, shouldn't this post better be in [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: @VincentG Maybe you're right... Can I move it? (Really newbie on stack overflow...)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one:

```
sName = Left(sName & Space(30), 30)
```

And I think it's better to use bookmarks as placeholders instead of using Range(start, end)

[How to change programmatically the text of a Word Bookmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483446/how-to-change-programmatically-the-text-of-a-word-bookmark)

Comment: I'll certainly look into the bookmarks, I've already read about it and it definitely seems very useful. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code needs some Trim's, in order to avoid mistaken spaces before and after the names (when you use some inputboxes, I mean). 
And you need to verify input dates, too. 
For string concatenation, use the ampersand (&) better than the plus sign (+), in order to avoid mistaken sums.
Instead of Chr(10) I have some recommendations in order to make your code more readable:

```
Chr(13) = vbCr
Chr(10) = vbLf
Chr(13) & Chr(10) = vbCrLf
```

Verify that the files you are indicating exist.

Comment: The string concatenation is kind of a habit from Java, I guess ;) But indeed, better use the ampersand. Some Trim's could also help a lot (Spaces after the input don't really matter in my code, but spaces before the input could screw up the lay-out of my doc). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using Range with numerical values is definitely not reliable. Bookmarks, as Tim suggests or content controls if this is Word 2007 or later. Content Controls are Microsoft's recommendation, going forward, but I don't see any particular advantage one way or the other for your purpose.

Looking at all the InputBox calls I have to wonder whether displaying a VBA UserForm for the input might not be better? All the input fields in one place, rather than flashing multiple prompts. You can validate for correct input before the UserForm is removed from the screen, etc.

Comment: I'll definitely look into the UserForm's. (Figured something like that should exist, but didn't really look into it.) Thanks!