# Find Wordbookmark based on a variable using vba from Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I have code which posts data from MS Access into a bookmark in a word precedent. it works perfectly.

```vb
With Oapp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
    .Item("Complaint").Range.Text = "insert this text"
End With
```

The issue is that i want to make the Word bookmark a variable because this will change depending on which template is being used.  Ultimately i want to store the bookmark in a field or get the user to enter the bookmark where the text is being used.  But for now i am having an issue replacing "Complaint" with a variable as every time i do this, the bookmark can no longer be found.  I thought that something like this would work.

```vb
BMName = "Complaint"

With Oapp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
    .Item(BMName).Range.Text = "insert this text"
End With
```

I have tried all different combinations of inverted commas but no matter what i do i cant get word to find the bookmark using a variable string.  I thought that this should be a simple process. Does anyone have any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: One you change the bookmark text, the bookmark is gone. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483446/how-to-change-programmatically-the-text-of-a-word-bookmark